# alternative or solution for UNION not to have data ordered manually

Tags: mysql

This question is concerning indexing or alternatives to UNION that would work the same.

In further example we assume `title` `text` and `content` are having `fulltext` as `index`

Imagine we have three statements

```
SELECT title as text FROM news ORDER BY score DESC
SELECT name as text FROM pages ORDER BY score DESC
SELECT content as text FROM comments ORDER BY score DESC
```

We can combine them (notice that we order them manually)

```
SELECT title as text FROM news ORDER BY score DESC
UNION
SELECT name as text FROM pages ORDER BY score DESC
UNION
SELECT content as text FROM comments ORDER BY score DESC
```

Now we have `text` that we can print but an order will be 1)news 2)pages 3)comments

*It is very bad since we want those ordered differently possibly by score*

Accordingly, we can combine all these `THREE SELECTS` into `ONE SELECT` and order them

```
SELECT text FROM (
   SELECT title as text FROM news ORDER BY score DESC
   UNION
   SELECT name as text FROM pages ORDER BY score DESC
   UNION
   SELECT content as text FROM comments ORDER BY score DESC
) as combination
```

Now we can `ORDER` it by `score`

*Again, this is very bad because scores are based per table not per whole selection*

So, we move on, and my question comes closer.

Next step is to introduce `MATCH() and AGAINST()` and we write

```
SELECT text, MATCH(text) AGAINST ('anything') as total_score FROM (
       SELECT title as text FROM news ORDER BY score DESC
       UNION
       SELECT name as text FROM pages ORDER BY score DESC
       UNION
       SELECT content as text FROM comments ORDER BY score DESC
    ) as combination ORDER BY total_score DESC
```

We are done! Everything should work perfect if not MATCH(`text`) appearing not to be indexed as fulltext.

An error appears: Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

Now a consufion comes and there is probably nothing left but somehow make `text` a `FULLTEXT`. Unfortunately, there is no such column as `text` existing in database, say you cannot find it in phpmyadmin to make it `FULLTEXT` that way.

I thought of extending `name as text` further to make it close to `name as text type fulltext` or something similar which I could not find anywhere.

Help me out please, I would like to hear anything, maybe there is another way of getting around in such situation? I don't know. I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2):

Use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

`UNION` *sorts* the unioned result set *and* discards duplicates (if any).

`UNION ALL` preserves order as selected (and preserves duplicates, if any)

Comment: I want something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13904885/fulltext-search-scores-calculated-not-from-all-given-tables Please see it if you have time, otherwise thanks for responding.